# Hello could somebody help me modify an interesting indicator?

Tags: mql4, mt4

I got this indicator for mt4, I would like somebody to help me modify it so I can input an integer to select how many bars should be plotted. normally it will plot infinite bars, I'd like to be able to select the number of MTF bars the indicator should plot. This to eliminate the lag when changin timeframes, I imagine the lag is because of the big amount of MTF candles plotted.

Other change that I would really apreciate, if you see when open and close price is exactly the same it will not create a doji, it will only show wicks, not the classic horizontal line for a doji.

I paid a coder to make this, now he's chargin plus to make this changes, I tried to make them myself copying an indicator that has that function but my coding skills are hugely limited.

Thanks.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                              MTF_Candles.mq4     |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Ab Moncada"
#property version   "1.0"
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window


enum enumTimeFrames{

   m1 = PERIOD_M1,   //M1
   m5 = PERIOD_M5,   //M5
   m15 = PERIOD_M15, //M15
   m30 = PERIOD_M30, //M30
   h1 = PERIOD_H1,   //H1
   h4 = PERIOD_H4,   //H4
   d1 = PERIOD_D1,   //D1
   w1 = PERIOD_W1,   //W1
   mn1 = PERIOD_MN1  //MN1
};

//input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES MTF_Period = PERIOD_H1;   //Timeframe
input enumTimeFrames MTF_Period = h1;    //Timeframe
input color UpColor = clrGainsboro;                  //ColorBulls
input color DownColor = clrGainsboro;              //ColorBears

input bool LineType = false;                    //Background
input ENUM_LINE_STYLE LineStyle = STYLE_DOT;    //LineStyle
input int LineWidth = 3;                        //LineWidth


string indiName = "MTF_CandleStick";

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit(){
//--- indicator buffers mapping

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+  
void OnDeinit(const int reason){

   objDelete(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period));

}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
//---

   if(MTF_Period <= _Period) return(0);

   int limit = rates_total - prev_calculated;

   if(limit > 0){
      objDelete(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period));
      limit = rates_total-1;
   }
   else{
      if(MTF_Period < 1440) limit = MTF_Period/_Period;
      else limit = 1;
   }

   for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){

      double mtfOpen, mtfClose, mtfHigh, mtfLow;
      int first, last=0;

      if(MTF_Period < 1440){

         if(MathMod(time[i], MTF_Period*60) != 0) continue;

         first = i;

         for(int t=i-1; t>=0; t--){

            if(time[i]+MTF_Period*60 <= time[t]){
               last = t+1;
               break;
            }
         }

         mtfOpen = open[first];
         mtfClose = close[last];
         mtfHigh = high[iHighest(NULL, 0, MODE_HIGH, first-last+1, last)];
         mtfLow = low[iLowest(NULL, 0, MODE_LOW, first-last+1, last)];
      }
      else{

         if(time[Bars-1] > iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i)) break;

         mtfOpen = iOpen(NULL, MTF_Period, i);
         mtfClose = iClose(NULL, MTF_Period, i);
         mtfHigh = iHigh(NULL, MTF_Period, i);
         mtfLow = iLow(NULL, MTF_Period, i);

         first = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i), false);
         if(TimeHour(time[first]) != 0) first--;

         if(i > 0){
            last = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i-1), false);
            if(TimeHour(time[last]) == 0) last++;
         }

         /*
         if(MTF_Period == 1440){
            first = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i), false);
            if(i > 0) last = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i-1), false)+1;
         }
         else{
            first = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i), false)-1;
            if(i > 0) last = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, MTF_Period, i-1), false);
         }
         */
      }

      if(mtfOpen <= mtfClose){
         Rectangle(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_body"+IntegerToString(i), first, mtfOpen, last, mtfClose, UpColor, LineStyle, LineWidth);
         TrendLine(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_shadow"+IntegerToString(i), (first+last)/2, mtfClose, mtfHigh, UpColor, LineWidth);
         TrendLine(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_tail"+IntegerToString(i), (first+last)/2, mtfOpen, mtfLow, UpColor, LineWidth);
      }
      else{
         Rectangle(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_body"+IntegerToString(i), first, mtfOpen, last, mtfClose, DownColor, LineStyle, LineWidth);
         TrendLine(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_shadow"+IntegerToString(i), (first+last)/2, mtfOpen, mtfHigh, DownColor, LineWidth);
         TrendLine(indiName+IntegerToString(MTF_Period)+"_tail"+IntegerToString(i), (first+last)/2, mtfClose, mtfLow, DownColor, LineWidth);
      }
   }

//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return(rates_total);
}


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

void Rectangle(string name, int index1, double price1, int index2, double price2, color Rcolor, int Rstyle, int Rwidth){

   long id = ChartID();

   if (ObjectFind(name) != 0) {

      ObjectCreate(id, name, OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, Time[index1], price1, Time[index2], price2);
      ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_COLOR, Rcolor);
      if(LineType) ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_STYLE, Rstyle);
      ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, Rwidth);
      ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_BACK, !LineType);
      //ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT, false);
      ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_SELECTABLE, false);
      ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_HIDDEN, true);
   }
   else{
      ObjectMove(name, 0, Time[index1], price1);
      ObjectMove(name, 1, Time[index2], price2);
   }

   ChartRedraw(id);
}

void TrendLine(string name, int position, double price1, double price2, color Tcolor, int Twidth){

   long id = ChartID();

   if (ObjectFind(name) != 0) {

     ObjectCreate(id, name, OBJ_TREND, 0, Time[position], price1, Time[position], price2);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_COLOR, Tcolor);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, Twidth);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_BACK, true);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT, false);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_SELECTABLE, false);
     ObjectSetInteger(id, name, OBJPROP_HIDDEN, true);
   }
   else{
     ObjectMove(name, 0, Time[position], price1);
     ObjectMove(name, 1, Time[position], price2);
   }

   ChartRedraw(id);
}

void objDelete(string basicName){

   for(int i=ObjectsTotal();i>=0;i--){
      string ObjName = ObjectName(i);
      if(StringFind(ObjName, basicName) >=0) ObjectDelete(ObjName);
   }
}
```